# Is there a decision procedure for analytic continuation?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces, analytic-continuation

Let an analytic element be a power series associated with an open disc of the complex plane over which the series is convergent. W.l.o.g. assume the series is a Taylor expansion about the center of the disc. It is easy to show that analytic continuation is an equivalence relationship between analytic elements.

Given two analytic elements $(U, f)$ and $(V, g)$, how can we tell whether they are in the same class? Obviously if $f$ and $g$ are both polynomials of degrees at most $n$ we could see if the two are in the same class by evaluating at $n + 1$ points. On the other extreme: even comparing coefficients of two general series may take infinite steps. So let me bifurcate the question:

- Without concern for computability, what can we say in general on how to decide if two analytic elements are in the same class?
- What restrictions do we need to restore computability to this question?

Comment: Not even equality on reals is decidable, how could this be?

Comment: @Arno: Maybe the OP does not have computability in mind. Maybe he thinks of: if $(U,f)$ and $(V,g)$ are analytic elements, and $U \cap V = \emptyset$, how can we tell whether there exists $(U \cup V, F)$ such that $F = f$ on $U$ and $F = g$ on $V$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Arno,@Alex is right. I will add his comment to the question to clarify. Obviously if the A.E.s are polynomials of degrees at most n, we can just pick any n+1 points on the plane to see if they are equivalent. If such questions can not be answered for general A.E.s what restrictions do we need? For example what if the power series f: N->C is inductively defined?

Comment: @zhtprog "How can we tell" is either incredibly vague, or the answer is: "We can't." If you want a meaningful question, you could ask "What is the complexity (in the sense of descriptive set theory) of having a joint analytic continuation?". The definition itself is a $\Sigma^1_1$, so if the problem is indeed $\Sigma^1_1$-complete, there is no simpler way to express this.

Comment: The practical answer is to look for an alternative representation for the analytic elements, such that they would have overlapping domains of convergence where they could be compared. E.g., the some integral representations converge in a half-plane, other (non-power) series approximations converge on non-disc domains, etc. I doubt that this approach can be made into an algorithm, but it does sometimes work in practice.

Comment: @Arno, I am not familiar with the complexity question you raised. I am interested in formalizing complex analysis/Riemann surface using power series and continuation and what kind of proof automation can be done in such a framework.

Comment: @zhtprog Your edit makes less sense than the previous version. Do you want to restrict your powerseries to having rational (or maybe algebraic coefficients) to make your argument for polynomials actually go through? Or maybe taking a step back, are you looking for an algorithm in a formal sense at all?

Comment: @Igor Thanks for the comment. I want to be sure I am not missing already discovered algorithms (even if it only works in some highly restricted situations).

Comment: @Arno, I am thinking of decidability as showing whether two logic formulae using defined primitives and logical connectives can be transformed into each other through finite amount of deductions.

Comment: @zhtprog Ok, so what logical formalism do you want to use? If you put arithmetic in, is all very undecidable straight away. If you don't put arithmetic in, how can you make sense of powerseries? You might get away with a two-sorted setting using a very weak arithmetic on the natural numbers, and treat the complex numbers separately. But I still think the question you ought to be asking is about $\Sigma^1_1$-completeness.

Comment: @Arno, see [quantifier elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_elimination) for example. One can reduce one representation to another. Deciding the truthfulness of a formula like: $ \exists x\in \mathbb {R} .(a\neq 0\wedge ax^{2}+bx+c=0)\ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ a\neq 0\wedge b^{2}-4ac\geq 0 $ is not entirely vacuous and is considered arithmetic in my book.

Comment: Please use TeX, not triple backquotes, to delimit math.  I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

!!Without regard for computability!!
One classic criterion is this.  $(U,f)$ analytically continues to $(V,g)$ iff there is a finite sequence $(U_k,f_k), k=0,\dots,n$ of analytic elements,
with $(U_0,f_0) = (U,f)$ and $(U_n,g_n) = (V,g)$ where, for $k=1,\dots,n$, we have $U_{k-1}\cap U_k \ne \varnothing$ and $f_{k-1}(z) = f_k(z)$ for all $z \in U_{k-1}\cap U_k$.

---

A simple example.
Take $(U,f)$ where $f(z) = \log z$ where $f(1) = 0$ and $U$ is the disk $|z-1|<1$.
Take $(V,g)$ where $g(z) = \log(-z)+C$ where $g(-1) = C$, $C$ a fixed constant, and $V$ is the disk $|z+1|<1$.
Question: Is $(U,f)$ continuable to $(V,g)$?
Answer: If and only if $C$ is an odd integer multiple of $i\pi$.

Comment: Is not this just the definition of analytic continuation?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko   Of course.  At least is some texts.